# Flask - pass form input to url_for

Tags: python, html, flask

I have an HTML template that lets the user select a date via jQuery datepicker.

How can I pass the date selected into an action?

The idea is, the user selects a date, then that passes to Flask's route.py, via `app.route("/date/<date>")`

calendar.html

```
{% block topscripts %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/calendar.css') }}">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        });
    </script>    
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('specific_date', date='2019-04-11') }}">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"  name='go-to-date'></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="calendar-form">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So, when the user selects a date in the `datepicker` ID, I want to pass that date to the `url_for`.  Currently I hardcoded the date (`2019-04-11`) just to check that it works, and it does.  How can I have that part be dynamic to whatever the user selects in the Calendar?

...If it helps, here's in routes.py (`default_template()` is the function that renders the template in the end).:

```
@app.route("/date/<date>/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def specific_date(date):
    print("\n\nDate:", date, "\n\n")
    images = get_files_on(date)
    print("\n\nSpecific date images:", images)
    return default_template(date=date, image_list=images)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a POST request to the `/date` route like so.

Changes to `calendar.html`:

```html
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('specific_date') }}">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"  name='go-to-date'></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="calendar-form">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Changes to the `date` route:

```py
from flask import request

# only allow POST request method
@app.route("/date/", methods=["POST"])
def specific_date():
    # getting the date from the POST request
    date = request.form['go-to-date']
    print("\n\nDate:", date, "\n\n")
    images = get_files_on(date)
    print("\n\nSpecific date images:", images)
    return default_template(date=date, image_list=images)
```

Comment: Ah! I got so caught up in trying to do optional variables, I forgot I could do this instead.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help.